# Unity + Google Cardboard + GazeInput: Catch trigger events

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-vr

I'm developing a toy object visualizer with Unity 3D and Google VR (specifically Cardboard). I'm using the default, Google-provided, GazeInputModule to allow the player to interact with the app UI. When the reticle is not over a UI element or a clickable 3D object, and the trigger is held pressed, I'd like it to cause the camera to rotate around the center of the object that's being looked at when the user moves his head (instead of rotating around its own center).

So what I basically need is a way to catch trigger events that happen over empty space or unclickable objects. How would one go about doing that?

I've tried looking at the Unity EventSystem docs and the Google GrazeInput docs but I'm not sure how to make it work in my case. (I don't need detailed code, I'm mostly not sure where to start).